# Which jar is for ProcedureExecutionContext interface?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

ProcedureExecutionContext Interface is used in Gemfire XD for creating procedures. I couldn't find the jar used for it.

Comment: Found it... its sqlfire.jar

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-gemfire is not the appropriate tag for this question.  Technically, neither is gemfire, but unfortunately GemFireXD does not have a tag, yet.  I have informed the Gem team of this problem for future questions.  Thanks.